# Elasticsearch scroll not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running the following elasticsearch aggregation query

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/ae2015/_search/?scroll=1m' -d '{
            "size" : 0,
            "query":{"constant_score":{"filter": {"geo_bounding_box" : {"location": {"top_left" : [-180, 85],"bottom_right" : [180, -85]}}}}},
            "aggs":{
                "grid": {
                    "geohash_grid": {"field":"location","precision": 3},
                    "aggs": {
                        "count":{"sum":{"field":"count"}}
                    }
                }
            }
        }'
```

This returns a scroll_id as expected, but when I use it, the response is "empty", ie

```
{"_scroll_id":"xxx","took":936,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":13238893,"max_score":0.0,"hits":[]}}
```

It's as if scrolling doesn't work with aggregations.

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [official documentation on scrolling](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html):

> If the request specifies aggregations, only the initial search response will contain the aggregations results.

Comment: awwww, I missed that somehow. Thanks. I'm stuck then??? I tried raising the max_result_window on my index but it doesn't seem to change anything... still stuck on 10000

Comment: With scrolling you can retrieve all your millions of document (i.e. the `hits`), but aggregations are a different thing and you cannot "scroll" over them like you'd do with documents. `max_result_window` is only for documents/hits, not aggregations.

Comment: OK, yet the 10000 default limit seems to apply, any idea? maybe there is a different parameter for this?

Comment: There's no limit when using the scroll API

Comment: Sorry, I meant there seems to be a 10000 limit applying to my aggregation results. I thought this 10000 came from the max_result_window, but you say it's not. My question is, where is this 10000 limit coming from?

Comment: What makes you think that you have a 10000 limit in aggregations?

Comment: Because it always stops at 10000 and I can see on my map some areas are not covered (ie downloaded). Do you mind moving to a chat?

Comment: Oh, indeed, the `geohash_grid` has a [default size of 10000](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geohashgrid-aggregation.html#_options_3), so you can increase the `size` as you see fit.

Comment: Fantastic!!! I feel a bit stupid now, having you read the docs for me... I was too focused on this max_result_window, forgot to check the rest. Thanks!!!

Comment: No worries, glad we figured it out!