# Elasticsearch query not returning _scroll_id for scroll query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

We have an Elasticsearch cluster which all seems to be working fine except that scrolling does not work. When I do a query with a `?scroll=1m` querystring no `_scroll_id` is returned in the results.

To check if it was anything to do with the existing Indexes I created a new Index:

```
PUT scroll_test

POST scroll_test/1
{
    "foo": "bar"
}

POST scroll_test/2
{
    "foo": "baz"
}

POST /scroll_test/_search?scroll=1m
{
    "size": 1, 
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

returns

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "scroll_test",
            "_type": "1",
            "_id": "AV0N_R0jl33mdjPtW4uQ",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "foo": "bar"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

We have just done a rolling upgrade from v5.2 to v5.4.3 (cluster health is now green). Scrolling still does not work after upgrading to v5.4.3.

I am able to execute scroll based queries on a local Elasticsearch v5.4.2 instance.

Comment: That's strange. I executed the same requests as you on ES 5.4.3 and I get a scroll_id. What are you using to send the search/scroll request? Because this looks like the `?scroll=1m` parameter is cut/ignored.

Comment: I'm using the Sense Chrome plugin. I'm not getting `_scroll_id` returned using the .NET library either

Comment: I don't really have an idea right now. Maybe you could compare the configurations/plugins of both ES instances. Especially the modules and plugins you get listed via `GET /_nodes`. If there is no difference, then I'm out of ideas unfortunately.

Comment: did you solve this issues?

Answer (score 0):

After reading a lot of other questions, I took away these main ideas:

- [Aggregation can't scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39773815/253127)

  - the query I copied from the Kibana "Discover" page "inspect" button had this, but I don't know what it was doing, and I was able to remove it with seemingly fine results.
- [Don't use scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#scroll-search-results), and just use [`search_after`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after):

  - docs state:  **We no longer recommend using the scroll API for deep pagination. If you need to preserve the index state while paging through more than 10,000 hits, use the `search_after` parameter with a point in time (PIT).**

I don't know if aggregations also miss out on `search_after` but I am playing it safe by not using them for now.